# How to show data from query count(*) with autoload Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, autoload

I get into trouble when using autoload.
For example:

My Model: Dataload.php

```
public static function footer(){
        $text = "Copyright &copy; 2018 MyCompany";
        return($text);
    }
```

My View : view.php

```
<p class="xxx"><?php echo dataload::footer() ?></p>
```

It's possible to show.
But for this problem :

```
+------+------------+--------------+
| id   | name       | email_status |
+------+------------+--------------+
| 01   | Erick      | send         |
| 02   | Maya       | send         |
| 03   | Michael    | pending      |
+------+------------+--------------+
```

My Model : Dataload.php

```
public function emailsend(){
    return $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM user WHERE email_status = "send"');
}
```

My View:

```
<i class="ti ti-email"></i><span class="badge badge-primary"><?php echo dataload::emailsend() ?></span><span>Email</span>
```

So, why data does not show?

The result should show "2":
[image]

NB : forgive me for my english :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the function in model:

```
public function emailsend(){
    $q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_status = "send"'); // you can select user_id here
    return $q->num_rows(); // this will return count    
}
```

then use above function in view.

```
NOTE: replace '*' with specific unique id. no need to select all the records.
```

Comment: if this is worked for you then accept so that other user can get.

Answer (score 0):

Using active record:

```
public function get_count(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this-db->where('email_status', 'send');
    return $this->db->get('user')->count_all_results();
}

//usage

$count = $this->model->get_count();
var_dump($count); //outputs int of count
```

Notice this method isn't static, so we aren't using `::`, also it's considered bad practice to call a model method from the view in `CI`

Comment: I agree that calling a model from a view breaks the MVC pattern. But since the call is to a static (I assume the missing qualifier is a typo) it's not really any different than using a var passed to the view or of using a constant. There are a lot of people that will object to the use of static in OO PHP which IMO is the bigger question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [generate and return some "results"](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) from the query. Also, as shown, `emailsend()` is not defined as `static` so the call `dataload::emailsend()` is going to fail.

```
public static function emailsend(){
    //use method chaining instead of multiple lines with $this->db
    return $this->db
                ->query('SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM user WHERE email_status = "send"')
                ->row() //the query results
                ->total; //the item of interest in results
}
```

I'm just asking for the 'id' field. No point in asking for all with '*'. Query should be quicker asking only for one.